# How were glottal stops indicated in Akkadian cuneiform?

Tags: phonology, orthography, cuneiform, glottal-stop, akkadian

According to Huehnergard, Akkadian had a phonemic glottal stop. This makes sense, given the language's heritage.

However, he doesn't seem to mention it anywhere in the chapters on orthography, and I certainly have never seen cuneiform glyphs for (e.g.) *ʔa* as opposed to *a* (*).

So, how did Akkadian scribes mark glottal stops? And if they didn't—that is, if they wrote *naʔdum* "attentive" as *na-du-um* with no indication of the ʔ—how do we know the glottal stop existed at all, and didn't just disappear in Akkadian like Proto-Semitic **ʕ* and **h* did?

(*) Kloekhorst argues that certain glyphs could indicate the presence of a glottal stop in Hittite, the reflex of PIE **h₁* in certain environments, but this doesn't seem to be a mainstream view.

Comment: What do you mean "mainstream view"? Hittite is not in any way main stream one way or another.

Comment: @vectory Hittite is studied by a wide variety of linguists, and Kloekhorst's idea about glottal stops does not seem to be part of the mainstream consensus among them.

Comment: it's studied widely, perhaps, but rarely as in-depth, I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Huehnergard's grammar (appendix D.1.d), Babylonian scribes distinguished the sign  from the sign . The former was used for *VH*, and the latter for the glottal stop—some authors call it *'*, others call it *'V, V'* (so *na'du* "pious" would be transliterated either *na-'-du* or *na-a'-du*). In earlier periods and other regions, the two were interchangeable, so aleph is better-known as *VH₂*.

(The cuneiform glyphs don't display properly here: aleph should look like *HI* plus *AN*, while *VH* should have two extra verticals on the right.)

In Assyrian, glottal stops were sometimes indicated with "broken writings" *(C)VC-V(C)* (e.g. *uṣ-am* for *uṣ'am*; *uṣam* without a glottal stop would be spelled *ú-ṣa-am*). But this was never especially consistent—a broken spelling is a good indication that a glottal stop existed, but the lack of one doesn't indicate its absence.

Answer (score 1):

In Middle Babylonian the sign uh was specialized into writing ʔ specifically.
But as a rule, glottal stop has no explicit graphemic expression. It's a hidden potential phoneme.
I think the equation PIE *H1 = ʔ is false, anyway. What is your reference on Kloekhorst?

Comment: Kloekhorst's _Etymological Dictionary of the Hittite Inherited Lexicon_, pages 18 and 25-26. He argues that plene spelling of vowels can sometimes indicate a glottal stop, a reflex of PIE *_h₁_ or *_h₃_, as in _ne-e-a_ "turns" (which he says represents /neʔa/ < *_néiHo_). But, this idea doesn't seem to be widely accepted.

Comment: That said, though, I didn't know UH could be used to write ʔ, that's very interesting! Could you elaborate a little bit—did it represent the consonant in isolation, or did it mean generic Vʔ (like how UH could be used for AH, EH, IH)?

Comment: For example, you can have a look at the Chicago Assyrian Dictionary. See the tome with words starting with n. It's freely available online.